# possible JS "file browser"?

Tags: javascript, html

What I have been looking for is almost like a music player. Where it will display folders (artists) and then display the contents of that folder (music). This will allow for me to upload folders and files using FTP and then my users to play or download the files. I do not need any type of reading, editing, deleting features.

Here is a quick mockup of what I have pictured in my head:

[image: mockup]

If anyone has any idea of what this is called or where to look for something please let me know because I have not been able to find anything close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with pure HTML/Javascript.  You will need some other coding framework/language to access the file system, because client-side Javascript does not have file system access.

[Update]
As some users have noted, Javascript framesworks such as Node.js could be used to gain file system access.

Comment: Do you recommend a language I should look at?

Comment: You will need not only the language, but to install the webservice as well. Most people around here use: php and apache, or asp.net (c#) and IIS

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a web application. This will involve the usual webserver+web framework+clientside javascript stack. If you want to do this all in js, use something based on node.js on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

I built a desktop-like media player  based on Chrome's `webkitdirectory` a few years ago.

Here's a demo of the attribute https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/demos/upload_directory/index.html (Only works in Google Chrome afaik). Just select some folder and there you go.

On non-Chrome browsers the same is still possible but since there is no support for `directory` attribute in the input element, it will be less convenient to select files. Also on Firefox you would need MP3 decoder implemented in user code.